# Vue3 Copy Router Path to Clipboard with User Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, routes, vue-router

I have a search system set up that loads a datatable of every account from an API call, then once you select the account ID, it will place that account ID in a store, and route you to the user's Dashboard where it then populates the information based on that ID.

```
store.setSelectedUser(data.id)
router.push(user/dashboard)
```

Therefore, the URL/Route name is displayed as such for every account: `user/dashboard`

However, I need the users to be able to press a button and copy the URL to their clipboard for sending the account link through emails and etc., where the URL will route them to that user's dashboard and display the correct data (assuming they are authenticated).

I don't have much experience using Vue router at the moment, so assistance would be appreciated in this regard

Thanks!

---

EDIT: After doing more research regarding vue router, I believe what I'm looking for is a way to deep link to a specific user from a shared link

Since the user's ID is within a store, I need the URL (for instance, `localhost:1234/user/dashboard`) to append the specific user's ID when copied from that page (`localhost:1234/user/dashboard+id:1111111` or something of the sort), and then intercept said query parameters when the link activated and the user is taken to that dashboard, so the store can be updated

Still looking into vue router more, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying to clipboard is done using the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) and it's `writeText()` function.

The path of the current route is contained within Vue Router's [route object](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object).  You can get the domain from the standard [window.location object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).  You could actually get the full URL from just `window.location.href`, but that's up to you.

#### Edit:

If the link needs to be for a specific profile based on an ID in your store, you'll have to append the ID to the URL. You'll also need to make sure your router can navigate to the dashboard with such a URL. The created hook of your dashboard component can handle setting the store's user ID if it exists in the URL, which you can then use for loading that user's information on the page.

```html
<button @click="copyURL">copy URL to clipboard</button>
```

```js
computed: {
  userId () {
    return this.$store.state.userId
  }
}
methods: {
  copyURL() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.origin + this.$route.path + "/" + this.userId);
    window.alert('URL copied to clipboard!')
  }
},
created() {
  if (this.$route.params.id) {
    this.$store.state.userId = this.$route.params.id;
  }
}
```

**router.js**

will navigate to the dashboard given either path: `/user/dashboard/` or `/user/dashboard/12345`

```js
routes: [
  // dynamic segments start with a colon. append '?' to make optional
  { path: '/user/dashboard/:id?', component: Dashboard }
]
```

Comment: so this worked for grabbing the initial route URL, such as `localhost:1234/user/dashboard`, but how would one append a query parameter that could then be intercepted when another person activates that link, so the parameter (in this instance, the user's ID), could be sent to the store for updating?

I edited the initial post for more information, hope that helps, thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Basically, append the ID from the store to the link, then in the component's `created` hook set the store's ID with the ID in the URL if it exists (which it will if the person is navigating to the page with a link like `/user/dashboard/12345`).  Might also need to update your `router.js` file to handle the URL with an optional ID param which is also in my updated answer.

Comment: Updated the files according to your edit, and when I attempt to follow the link (in this instance, I changed it to direct the user to the homepage, store the user ID, and then router.push to the user/dashboard, so its now `localhost:1234/home/1111111`), it prompts this error in the console:
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON        home/1111111:1`

The page seems to re-login due to the Auth0 set up, so going to look into that, as it could be responsible for it.